# Completeness of 2-category of Monoidal Categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, limits-colimits

Is the 2-category of monoidal categories complete?
If not, can any conditions be imposed to satisfy completeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with 2-categories, the notion of completeness is not quite as clear-cut as in 1-categories. See [the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit) for more information. It should be relatively straightforward to check directly that monoidal categories have all 2-limits, though, and that the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Cat}$ preserves them. For instance, the product of some monoidal categories is their product as in $\mathsf{Cat}$, with the monoidal product defined in the obvious way. A systematic way to see this is to note that monoidal categories are the [pseudoalgebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudoalgebra+for+a+2-monad) for the "free monoid" 2-monad on the 2-category $\mathsf{Cat}$, and [Blackwell, Kelly, and Power](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404989901606) showed that such 2-categories always have all 2-limits.

The intuition is similar to constructing limits of algebras for a 1-monad on $\mathsf{Set}$, say. In this setting, it's pretty intuitive to work out that to create a limit in $\mathsf{Grp}$ or $\mathsf{Ring}$ or $\mathsf{Vect}$, say, you simply take the limit of the underlying sets and then there's really only one way you could possibly define the operations -- everything just works. This is abstracted to argue that the category of algebras for a 1-monad has limits created in the base category. Then the argument for 2-monads is really just the same thing one category level higher - modulo strictness issues.

**EDIT**

As Kevin Carlson  points out below, I cut too many corners in the above. In order to use the BKP result, you have to know that the monoidal categories are actually the *strict* algebras for a 2-monad with rank, which is also true, but the 2-monad in question is not quite as snappy to desribe as the "free monoid monad" $T$. Rather, It's the 2-monad $T'$ that freely adjoins all the structure of a monoidal category, including images of the $\otimes$ functor as well as associator morphisms, etc. all subject to certain equations of morphisms (but not of objects!).

But is there a conceptual way that we can say that the free monoidal category monad $T'$ is a "corrected" version of the free monoid monad $T$? Indeed there is. Steve Lack [constructs](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607646) a 2-model structure (i.e. a $\mathsf{Cat}$-enriched model structure) on the 2-category of finitary monads on $\mathsf{Cat}$ (or any other reasonable 2-category). This model structure is lifted from a trivial model structure on the 2-category of endo-2-functors of $\mathsf{Cat}$. And in this model structure, $T'$ is a cofibrant replacement for $T$. And in general the 2-category of strict algebras for the cofibrant replacement is biequivalent to the 2-category of pseudoalgebras for the original 2-monad (although to be honest I don't quite see why this should always be the case on general grounds).

Comment: BKP shows no such thing. They construct pseudolimits in 2-categories of strict T-algebras, whereas you claim strict 2-limits in a 2-category of pseudo-algebras, namely monoidal categories.

Comment: I once read the paper but my memory is hazy, so I'll just quote from the abstract: "We show that $T-Alg$ admits pseudo-limits and certain other limits". Also in the abstract: $T-Alg$ means the category of pseudoalgebras for a 2-monad $T$; they use $T-Alg_s$ to mean the strict algebras. Pseudo-limits are in particular bilimits, which is what I mean by "2-limit" here, following the nlab. They do assume that $T$ has rank, which the free monoid 2-monad does. Have I mangled something?

Comment: No, T-alg is the strict algebras with pseudo morphisms. 2-limits means strict limits-not pseudo limits. This is all at the bottom of page 2 if you can access the paper.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I did mangle it, and how! So I guess to use BKP you have to know that monoidal categories are the strict algebras for a different 2-monad, which is also true, but more annoying. I think there are systematic Australian ways to see this -- it would seem to require a bit more than the existence of a left adjoint to the inclusion $T-Alg_s \to T-Alg$ that BKP talk about. I'll see if I can track down the references....

Comment: Yeah, you have to replace the monad, instead of the algebra-I'm not sure where that is either. Ah-I see you've found it, great!